# starting a django server with cmd

Tags: python, django, cmd, command-line

i created a virtual environment for django and im trying to start the server but i keep running into this problem

```
(Django-8VqULu7_) C:\Users\rondo11\Documents\learn how to program\learning python\Django>py manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

what is the problem?

Comment: The last line gives you the possible solutions. Are you sure you installed Django in the virtual environment?

Comment: you forgot to start virtual environment. if you dont know how to create a virtual environment than steps are below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Create a virtual evironment

`pipenv shell install django` install django in virtual environment

`pipenv shell` to run the virtual environment

`python manage.py runserver` to start the server